# Android Bluetooth connection using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord without MAC address

Tags: android, bluetooth, mac-address, rfcomm, beacon

I am creating an application for communicating Android mobile devices with Bluetooth beacons. I have successfully achieved this between one beacon (which acts as a client) and one android mobile device (acts as the server, listening for the connection). Please find the code snippet below,

**Client app**

```
BluetoothDevice device = mBluetoothAdapter.getRemoteDevice(MACaddress);
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("f3c74f47-1d38-49ed-8bbc-0369b3eb277c"));
mBluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
socket.connect();
```

**Server app**

```
mmServerSocket = mBluetoothAdapter.listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord("NAME", UUID.fromString("f3c74f47-1d38-49ed-8bbc-0369b3eb277c"));
socket = mmServerSocket.accept();
```

This works fine with one mobile device (server) where I am able to obtain its `MACaddress` by scanning nearby Bluetooth devices. But consider the case when there are around 20-25 mobile devices present in range - scanning would consume so much time. I would like to do this without performing a scan.

Is there a way to achieve this without using the server's `MACaddress`?  Can the connection be established with the unique UUID alone? Please note that I do not want to pair the devices.

Any other solution in this regard is also welcome. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a socket connection to a bluetooth device without identifying the bluetooth device itself, and the unique identifier for bluetooth device is a MAC Address.  Even if there were an Android API that would allow you to do this via UUID alone, the underlying implementation would still have to search for nearby devices (e.g. scan) and find one that is accepting socket connections using the UUID.  So the scanning mentioned in the question would still have to happen.

Yes, scanning can use a bit of power and CPU intensive if a number of bluetooth devices are around.  You can limit this two ways:

1. Only scan briefly.  For your use case, it seems you could just scan for a few seconds then stop once you find a supporting device.  This should not be too resource intensive.
2. Use scan filters on Android 5.0+ to match only the devices that you are interested in.

Comment: Thanks David! I'm going to try out the scan filters in BLE. However as a temporary work around, is there way to mock/ spoof the MAC address of the server through code? In this way I could avoid the scan since I know the MAC beforehand. I found several methods of MAC spoofing through device rooting and various third party apps, but none through java code!

Comment: My experience is the same.  You need low level access with root to spoof the MAC.

Comment: I created a scan filter using UUID and it takes 3-4 seconds to yield a result with just one server. It raised another doubt - does the filter make the scan slow? since scanner fragment has to check for the matching UUID. I was hoping that I could scan 1 device per second, is it possible? your thoughts please.. @davidgyoung

Comment: If you turn off the scan filter, do you get more frequent callbacks?  I would not expect so.

Comment: Is there a way to obtain faster result using scan filter (say, scan 1 device per second) ?

Comment: You should get one callback for each packet received.  If the device is sending 10 advertising packets per second, you should get nearly 10 callbacks per second (some packets are lost in transit.)  This is true regardless of filters.

Comment: David, i tried filtering using the method 'startLeScan(UUID[],BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback)' but not getting the proper output even with matching UUID. Any idea why?

Comment: If you leave the UUID array blank in the `startLeScan` call, does it return results?  If so, I suspect something must be wrong with the UUID setup.  You might open a new question showing a code example scanning without filtering (and showing the UUID result returned) and another example showing the filter you set up that returns no results.

Comment: do you have any insights on this problem? I changed my server from android to Raspberry Pi on Python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477848/insecure-rfcomm-connection-in-python