# Insecure rfcomm connection in Python

Tags: python, bluetooth, raspberry-pi, rfcomm

I would like to establish a bluetooth connection from an android device to a Raspberry Pi without pairing. The language used in RPi is Python. I am connecting using `createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord` from android.

However the connection is established only when the two devices are paired. Is there an equivalent of `listenUsingInsecureRfcommWithServiceRecord` in Python?

**Raspberry Pi code**

```
server_sock=BluetoothSocket( RFCOMM )
server_sock.bind(("",PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)
port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "f3c74f47-1d38-49ed-8bbc-0369b3eb277c"

advertise_service( server_sock, "AquaPiServer",
                   service_id = uuid,
                   service_classes = [ uuid, SERIAL_PORT_CLASS ],
                   profiles = [ SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE ], 
                   )

    client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
    print "Accepted connection from ", client_info
```

**Android code**

```
BluetoothDevice device = blueAdapter.getRemoteDevice(RPi_MAC);
BluetoothSocket socket = device.createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord(UUID.fromString("f3c74f47-1d38-49ed-8bbc-0369b3eb277c"));
blueAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
socket.connect();
```

Comment: I don't believe this is possible to do without pairing.  The Bluetooth pairing process is what authorizes the two devices to communicate.

Comment: I'm curious why it's not possible since insecure rfcomm works perfectly fine in android. Is it a limitation of Raspberry Pi?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to connect to the Raspberry Pi without pairing. For this I had to make the RPi discoverable. Then I used `socket.connect()` from my Nexus running on Marshmallow. By doing this I was able to get the MAC address of my Nexus in the RPi. Only problem is that I get a pairing request every time I connect but the MAC address was what I wanted.

Thanks for your inputs David!